# Energy in transients vs. steady state

Tags: frequency, energy

In something like a regular household, how much energy consumed is transient power vs steady state and what kind of frequency distribution does it have, roughly?
I imagine the vast bulk of the energy being in the lower frequencies but have been unable to find any information backing that up.
Aside from curiosity, the reason I ask is I am currently working on an Amp hour monitoring project for off-grid systems using coulomb counting (measuring voltage drop across a current shunt) and filtering that with a low pass filter before ADC, just wondering if this would cause an inaccuracy worth worrying about.
Thanks.

Comment: You won't monitor energy by coulomb counting. Energy is the integral of power and power = V x I.

Comment: @Andyaka amp-hour monitoring?

Comment: That is not energy as per originally stated in your question (now corrected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transients, by definition, are very short period.  And (in the context of the vague scenario you describe) they're the effect of either infrequent load switching, or highly periodic 'switch-mode' noise that may result from use of a DC-to-AC inverter, for example, or an actual load drawing non-DC or non-sinusoidal current.  The former can probably be ignored without a second thought, due to the comparative rarity of them.

As for highly periodic 'switching noise', well, "it depends" on the specifics of the equipment (inverter?) & load in use.  If it were me, I'd want to see at least a voltage waveform, & ideally a current waveform, with the system under various loads, to "see if you have a problem" that needs to be accounted for in your measurements, or not.  *But* my gut feeling is that the energy in any such 'noise' is probably going to at least 2, probably more like 3- orders of magnitude less (one hundredth or one thousandth) energy than the actual steady-state (DC or sinusoidal) load - if that guess is actually the case, then you can make a call as to whether that matters to your desired measurement accuracy.  In a "regular household", I'd expect not :)